# Roblox Studio- Infinite yield possible

Tags: roblox

I am trying to code a FPS Game but when I tap the button to pick a gun it does not give it to me but instead says  Infinite yield possible, anyways this is my code:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.AKEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local ak = game.ReplicatedStorage.Weapons.AK:Clone()
    ak.Parent = player:WaitForChild("BackPack")
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

In very little time I have already found what happened, so if it happens to you:
Backpack had a capital P and it was meant to be with a lower case P lol!